# How do i pass a useReducer state using Context? - React Native

Tags: reactjs, state

I have this useReducer state:

```
    const initialLoginState = {
    isLoading: true,
    userName: null,
    userToken: null,
    userPassword: null,
    userRegistrado:false,
    };
```

Which belongs to:

```
const [loginState, dispatch] = React.useReducer(loginReducer, initialLoginState)
```

And i'm passing 2 context (one with the value of some functions, and the StateContext, which is the one i use to pass the loginState.

```
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
    <StateContext.Provider value = {loginState}>

      //stacks and drawer
      
    </StateContext.Provider>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
```

And this is how i get the value, in my signUp screen:

```
const {loginState} = React.useContext(StateContext);
```

But when i try to get the value from loginState.userRegistrado i get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userRegistrado' of undefined

I'm importing the context like this:

> import {AuthContext, StateContext} from '../../Components/Context';

And this is how i create the context:

```
    import React from 'react';

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const StateContext = React.createContext();
```

EDIT (my reducer code):

```
      const initialLoginState = {
    isLoading: true,
    userName: null,
    userToken: null,
    userPassword: null,
    userRegistrado:false,
  };
  //funcion del reducer, acepta un estado inicial y una accion
  const loginReducer = (prevState, action) =>{
    switch (action.type){
      //el primer case es para cada vez que el usuario abre la app
      case 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN':
        return{
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'LOGIN':
        return{
          ...prevState,
          userName: action.id,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'LOGOUT':
        return{
          ...prevState,
          userName: null,
          userToken: null,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'REGISTER':
        return{
          ...prevState,
          //userName: action.id,
          //userToken: action.token,
          //userPassword: action.password,
          isLoading: false,
          userRegistrado:true,
        };
    }
  }

  const [loginState, dispatch] = React.useReducer(loginReducer, initialLoginState)
```

Comment: Post your reducer code. Maybe you are setting the object to undefined?

Comment: @JMadelaine hi, i just edited it with my reducer code

Comment: You need to do something like `<AuthContext.Provider value={loginState}>`

Comment: @ShubhamVerma yeah that's what i did, but i'm using another context because i'm already using the AuthContext.Provider to send another value. I'm using <StateContext.Provider value = {loginState}>

Comment: @le0nicolas what is the error coming?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma  when i try to check if loginState.userRegistrado is true on my other screen, i get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'userRegistrado' of undefined

Comment: Can you add your code [here](http://react.new/)

Comment: @ShubhamVerma ok i just added it! I didn't paste all the code because it's a lot and will make it confusing. I copied in the App.js how i pass the value of my StateContext and in the signUp.js how i get the value from the StateContext. Can you see it?

Comment: @le0nicolas where is the url? Yeah its fine just add barebone what you are trying to do

Comment: @ShubhamVerma  does this work? [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-wiles-jrf83?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I SOLVED IT!!!!!!!!! OMGGG finally lmao, i was calling it the wrong way on my signUp screen. This is how i call it now, and it works: const {userRegistrado} = React.useContext(StateContext); I dont have to get the loginState, i have to use what's inside the loginState.

Comment: Haha nice. I eventually created sandbox to help you out: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bhabha-60stj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ShubhamVerma thanks anyway! i really appreciate the SO community in helping newbies like me haha! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I wasn't calling the state on my other screen, i was calling the loginState object, BUT i should've called the state itself.

This is how i was calling it:

```
const {loginState} = React.useContext(StateContext);
```

When i should've been calling it like this:

```
const {userRegistrado} = React.useContext(StateContext);
```

This is where i got the idea from: [link](https://hswolff.com/blog/how-to-usecontext-with-usereducer/)